# How do I set the size of a file opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED?

Tags: c, file, winapi, io

[One article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a783096-0bd4-456a-8430-fefa684fc6c8/setendoffile-and-overlapped-io?forum=vcgeneral) suggests: "You have to call `SetFilePointer` before calling `SetEndOfFile`" but the documentation for `SetFilePointer` explicitly states: "The file pointer that is identified by the value of the hFile parameter is not used for overlapped read and write operations.".

Edit: I opened a file with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, did a `SetFilePointer` to 4MB and called `SetEndOfFile`. I then did `SetFilePointer` to zero bytes from `FILE_BEGIN` and then wrote to it with `OVERLAPPED` structure's `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` flag set to `0xFFFFFFFF`. The write happened at the end of the file i.e. starting from the 4MB mark.

Comment: Are you truncating an existing file?  Why?

Comment: The most portable method is to open a new file, then start from the beginning and copy the content you want to keep to the new file.  Delete the original file.  Rename the new file as necessary.

Comment: You can open it twice. First open it synchronously and set the file size. Then reopen it in overlapped mode and update the contents.

Comment: `SetEndOfFile()` requires the handle's file pointer to be pre-set at the desired offset. But file handles opened in overlapped mode don't generally use the file pointer. So, how do you expect to use `SetEndOfFile()` on an overlapped file? What exactly are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar - *You can open it twice.* never need do this

Comment: @RemyLebeau - in general this not true - this will be work ok (but not efficient) for asynchronous files too

Comment: @ThomasMatthews not truncating; padding. Some code downstream expects the file to be a certain size.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm writing files in a format which requires files to be of a certain size so even before we start writing we call SetEndOfFile to set the file size but now I need to use overlapped I/O so want to be sure if I can use SetEndOfFile with overlapped I/O

Comment: you can use SetEndOfFile with overlapped I/O, but better never use this api at all. use SetFileInformationByHandle or NtSetInformationFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The file pointer that is identified by the value of the hFile
> parameter is not used for overlapped **read** and **write** operations."

yes. this is correct. but not for all I/O operations, but only for read and write ( and several others), but not for SetFilePointer ( `NtSetInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation` )

at first - what is *file pointer* ? look at [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) structure - the *CurrentByteOffset* - member that specifies the file offset, in bytes, associated with the file object - and so called *file pointer* in win32

note, that this member basically managed by I/O manager itself and not by (filesystem) driver.

we can get and set this member by call [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) and [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with [`FilePositionInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_position_information)

despite here noted :

> *The caller must have opened the file with FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT or FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT flag specified in the CreateOptions
> parameter.*

this is not exactly true, even if file opened without this flags ( i.e. with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` ) - usually this work (depend drom driver implementation). simply if file opened as synchronous - this operation handled by I/O manager itself (driver even not called). in case asynchronous file - request passed to driver. the filesystem drivers(fastfat, ntfs) handle this request by update `CurrentByteOffset` too.

why this for read/write ? because look for signature of this api - it have (optional for synchronous handles) `ByteOffset` parameter - and if it present - it used, otherwise it taked from `CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT`. for asynchronous handles - `ByteOffset` is mandatory parameter - it always must be not 0 ( or system return error invalid parameter) - so `CurrentByteOffset` in asynchronous read/write I/O never used. but this is not related to `NtSetInformationFile`

what is `SetFilePointer` do ? it call `NtSetInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation` ( really it also call and `NtQueryInformationFile` too).

what is `SetEndOfFile` do ? it first call `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation` - for get value of `CurrentByteOffset` (which you set by `SetFilePointer` ) and then call `NtSetInformationFile` with `FileEndOfFileInformation` and `FileAllocationInformation` ( this call is optimization only).

so `SetFilePointer` with `SetEndOfFile` will be work for any files. but not efficient. i suggest never use `SetFilePointer` at all. for concrete task - simply call `NtSetInformationFile` (the best) or if you not like ntapi - use [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) with `FileEndOfFileInfo` + `FileAllocationInfo`

```
        FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO eof = { * };
        SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileEndOfFileInfo, &eof, sizeof(eof));
        SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileAllocationInfo, &eof, sizeof(eof));
```